# How can I integrate Tailwind css into my Django project with Docker?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, node-modules, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use Tailwind CSS in my Django project running with Docker / Docker-compose. my Django container is built with python:3.9-slim, which has no npm built-in.

I am thinking to use node:15.4-alpine to install tailwind css. How can I do so? Can someone give me guidance on Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

I've tried to start with this [tailwind playground](https://github.com/chrislentz/tailwindcss-docker-playground). But I don't need to run the live-server.

Comment: You could use Docker [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), using `node:15.4-alpine` in the first stage to install Tailwind CSS, then switch to `python:3.9-slim` and copy the assets from the previous build stage into the final image.

Answer (score 2):

[here](https://medium.com/@lendinez/how-to-use-tailwind-in-django-and-not-die-in-the-attempt-2853eb164aa7) is the good example to use tailwind in Django. On top of that there is the python library which you can use for implementing the tailwind with Django, see here https://pypi.org/project/django-tailwind/